# How to record all dynamic videos in the process of capturing screen video with ffmpeg from a python program?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, robotframework, screen, capture

I have many robotframework test cases and in the first case, a ffmpeg command like the following is invoked to record the whole running process:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -f gdigrab -i desktop -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -preset ultrafast output.mkv
```

Whenever I firstly run all cases and then manuually run the above command from an addition command console, the recorded video always looks fine, it looks like all contents on the screen can be correctly captured.

However, once I execute the command the same as the above one in the first case by call the following code:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and then in the final test case the record process is stopped by calling the following code to tell ffmpeg that we want to stop the recording:

```
p.stdin.write(bytes("q",'UTF-8'))
```

the final result video only contain correct contents of the "start" and the "end" of the whole process, but all other contents no longer changed and seemd just a static image, which means all the dynamic effects on the screen cannot be captured.

Could anyone be so kind as to let me know what the matter is and how to solve it?

Comment: Maybe this is because ffmpeg cannot get the realtime screen after the calling to ```subprocess.Popen``` from RF's process and it will be OK after all test cases run finished, but what's the cause and how to address it by adjusting the python program?

Comment: My environment: python 3.7.4, FFmpeg 4.3.1-2020-11-19, and RF 3.1.2

Comment: It is run on windows7, can anyone offer a solution or give me some tips? Thanks first.